# itext 5 acroforms fields blank after migrating from itext 2

Tags: pdf, itext

In existing Java code using Itext 2.1.5, I replaced the jar with 5.5.8 and updated the import packages to itextpdf from lowagie.  The PDF so generated is now blank, whereas before it had the expected text.

The application's approach is similar to the demo at http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-fill-out-pdf-file-programmatically-acroform-technology.  One addition I have made, which I have seen in other examples, is to call stamper.partialFormFlattening(name) after setting each field.

I have confirmed during step-through debugging that after invoking form.setField(name, value) on the AcroForms object, I can evaluate the expression form.getField(name) in the debugger and get back the value I set.

The base PDF was created using Scribus 1.4.6, and saved from that as a version 1.4 PDF file.

Is there some step I am missing either in initialization or after setting the values that wasn't necessary in the earlier version?

Comment: Does your pdf have the **NeedAppearances** flag set to true?

Comment: It did not.  I just added a line as follows right after creating the stamper:

stamper.getWriter().getAcroForm().setNeedsAppearances(true);

None of the existing code used the writer or the form (it does use the AcroFields, though).  But, these result after doing this is still the same - blank fields.

It might be worth noting that the fields that were filled in no longer get highlighted when I view the pdf, while fields that weren't filled in do

Comment: *" I just added a line as follows right after creating the stamper: `stamper.getWriter().getAcroForm().setNeedsAppearances(true)`"*- Please try setting it to false.

Comment: I just tried that, but no change in result - still empty